# [ukrainian,russian]babel + amsmath redefinition command issue

Tags: amsmath, babel

While typesetting following document error `!LaTeX Error: Command \sh already defined` occur.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This is a test!
\end{document}
```

This because commands like `\sh` redefined in babel (russian, ukrainian). Havn't found definition of this particular command in `amsmath.sty` so how can it be redifined? And I'm using the same code and the same MiKTeX on other computer with Win10 where no errors at all while typesetting. I've updated all files without results. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I can get that with an older copy but with current texlive `File: ukraineb.ldf 2020/10/14 1.4e Ukrainian support for the Babel system` I get no error, what version of the ukraineb.ldf file does your log show?

Comment: miktex seems to have missed an update. I will make a bug report.

Comment: I have ```ukraineb.ldf``` file marked as ```2018/04/11 1.4c```

Comment: I opened the bug report: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/219. It should be resolved soon.

Comment: Just figured out that I have same file ```ukraine.ldf``` version on both computers (```2018/04/11 1.4c```). But different files ```asmmath.sty```. On Win10 I have ```amsmath.sty [2018/12/01 v2.17b]``` and it's works. On Win7 I have (probably after update) ```[2020/09/23 v2.17i]``` and it's still conflict with babel. Tried to replace bad one without results. Fixed one problem but found another ```!LaTeX Error: Command \negmedspace already defined.```.

Comment: you can't use an old amsmath with a new latex. miktex will update this soon. If you can't wait don't start to mix  old files in a new system, get instead a new ukraine.ldf from ctan.

Comment: You might, as a temporary workaround, try adding the `shorthands=off` option to `\babel` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks, they fixed the bug with old ```ukraineb.ldf``` and now it don't clashes with ```amsmath```. But I have another problem which points to ```xcntperchap.sty``` (I use this package) and I'm not sure that I have to create standalone question. While typesetting I get error message for  ```\c_zero deprecated```. I solved this problem by myself but I guess it should be done by updating this package.